# moment-timezone.js:476 Moment Timezone has no data for Asia/Jerusalem

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moments-timezone.js

but i get this exception:

```
moment-timezone.js:476 Moment Timezone has no data for Asia/Jerusalem
```

I went to tz [references](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json)

and i see `Asia/Jerusalem` exists.

So what can be the problem?

```
toolFilters.filter('dateAccordingToTimeZone', function ($filter) {
    // Gets the number of milliseconds pass from 1970 and convert it to time according to given timezone, currently
    // supported “Asia/Jerusalem” and “America/Los_Angeles”
    return function (milliSeconds, timeZoneId) {
        if (milliSeconds == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        var timeInt = parseInt(milliSeconds, 10);
        var response = "";

        if (timeZoneId === undefined) {
            response = moment(timeInt);

        } else if (timeZoneId.includes("/")) {        //like "America/New_York"
            response = moment.tz(timeInt, timeZoneId);

        } else if (timeZoneId.includes("GMT")) {
            var offset = timeZoneId.substring(3);    //like "GMT-08:00"
            response = moment(timeInt).utcOffset(offset);

        } else {
            response = moment(timeInt);
        }

        var response = response.format('MMM D, YYYY H:mm:ss');
        console.log(response);
        return response;
}
```

I have these imports:

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script> 
<script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you got the lib with data

Comment: has my answer resolved your issue?

Comment: @JoeWarner 
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>

Answer (score 4):

You need the moment-timezones-with-data.js lib

> http://momentjs.com/timezone/

without it, it doesn't have all the international timezones as they don't want to make it mandatory to have all timezone data.

> Working with moment-with-data
>
> ```js
> console.log(moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem'))
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Failing without the data

```js
  console.log(moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i already have moments and moments-tz as scripts `
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>`

Comment: yes but replace moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js for moment-timezone-with-data.js:)

Comment: I have to download it manually? because when i installed with npm it didn't add it offline

Comment: 'moment-timezone-with-data' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: oh sorry yeah just import moment-timezone-with-data instead

Comment: <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>

Comment: is there a case when i need both `moment.timezone.with-data `
 AND `moment. timezone` together or with data is including the `moment.timezone`????

Comment: no you need both i believe :) i think you can provide your own timezone stuff and when you include with data it includes EVERY timezone almost definitely to many for your usecase i.e it has ancient timezones ect